# Simple Recommendation system

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi everyone,
I am trying to build a really simple recommendation system. I can not think of the pseudocode behind it, but I know the logic.

John  buys A B C D E
Alex buys  A B X Y Z

I buy A B C F R

I would be recommended items from John since I have more matches with him. Therefore, items D and E would be recommended. It's very simple. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

This is the brute force way to do it. Probably not the most elegant but it works:

```
// $for = the user we are getting rec's for
// $user_array = the list of all users
function recommendations($for, $user_array) {

    // For storing the best matching user
    $best_match = array('name'=>'', 'count'=>0);

    foreach ($user_array as $name=>$items) {

        // If this user, skip
        if ($name==$for) continue;

        // Number of matching records
        $c = count(array_intersect($items, $user_array[$for]));

        // If better than the current best match, replace
        if ($c > $best_match['count']) {
            $best_match = array('name'=>$name, 'count'=>$c);
        }
    }

    // If no matches found, return false
    if ($best_match['count']==0)
        return false;

    // Return array of recommendations
    return array_diff($user_array[$best_match['name']], $user_array[$for]);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$users = array (
    'john' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
    'alex' => array('a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z'),
    'me' => array('a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'r')
);

print_r(recommendations('me', $users));
```

Comment: +1 for using `continue` instead of an "big" `if` statement. Anyway, it would be better if your code could use an object (for comparing `$thisUser->id` instead of just using a name, which could be the same for two users) and accessing data like `$thisUser->name`, `$thisUser->lastItemBought`, etc. It develops the idea though.

Comment: @AlejandroIván yes it definitely has some weaknesses... it would certainly be better to use in an OO fashion and using the string `name` is a horrible way to do it ... an id would be very necessary.

Comment: what is the use of $user_array[$best_match['name']] here?

Comment: @CodeLover Ya I thought that might be confusing... `$best_match['name']` is the name of the user with the most matches - a string. That string is used as the index of `$user_array` ... so if `$best_match['name']=='john'`, then `$user_array[$best_match['name']]` translates to `$user_array['john']`, which is the array of John's records.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation systems can be built with different algorithms like item based,user based,content based and other techniques.I generally go for implementing few algorithms and upon scaling find out the best one.
For instance if we use the collaborative filtering technique and association rules we find the confidence,lift and support in determining the product/category recommendations.
[market basket analysis for recommendations](http://www.saedsayad.com/association_rules.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a Recommendation System in Java then use Apache Mahout. According to your question, you have to use ItemBasedRecommendation and the algorithm would be LogLikelihoodSimilarity.

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("path/fileName.csv"));

ItemSimilarity similarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(model);

GenericItemBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericItemBasedRecommender(model, similarity);

List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(userNumberForRecommendation, numberOfRecommendation);

for(RecommendedItem recommendation:recommendations) {
        System.out.println(recommendation);
}
```